# BASH: IF / ELIF incorrect triggering

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need not just an answer for the following situation, but an explanation please.
There are 2 files - NEW and OLD:

```
touch NEW ; 
touch -t $(date -d '3 week ago' +%Y%m%d%H%M) OLD
```

Now i'm making the script to output different messages according to the results of comparison of a NEW file to the old one:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                           
if [[ "NEW" -ot "OLD" ]]                                                          
        then echo "file is old"                                                                                       
elif [[ "NEW" -nt "OLD" ]]                                                        
        then echo "file is new"                                                                                       
fi
```

But no matter which condition is correct, "file is old" will always be printed.

The same situation with IF ELSE FI statement.

File Information:

```
    stat NEW
  File: 'NEW'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd05h/64773d    Inode: 3227449730  Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (48935/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: (48935/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2017-06-02 20:53:27.461237303 +0000
Modify: 2017-06-02 20:53:27.461237303 +0000
Change: 2017-06-02 20:53:27.461237303 +0000
 Birth: -

stat OLD
  File: 'OLD'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd05h/64773d    Inode: 3227452336  Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (48935/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: (48935/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2017-06-02 20:29:05.607617334 +0000
Modify: 2017-05-12 20:20:00.000000000 +0000
Change: 2017-06-02 20:23:42.872363548 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Where am i wrong?

Comment: `$NEW` is not `NEW`.

Comment: BTW, `bash -x yourscript` would have made this fairly obvious, by logging `+ [[ '' -ot '' ]]` -- making it clear that it's comparing two empty strings as filenames.

Comment: Please show output of `echo NEW=$NEW OLD=$OLD`, `stat NEW` and `stat OLD`.

Comment: @Mikel, `bash -x` output is better than `echo` -- echo won't show hidden characters, expands globs if used unquoted, etc. Agreed that the `stat` output would be helpful, though a true [mcve] would let folks trying to answer the question generate that themselves.

Comment: stat NEW
  File: 'NEW'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd05h/64773d    Inode: 3227449730  Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (48935/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: (48935/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2017-06-02 20:53:27.461237303 +0000
Modify: 2017-06-02 20:53:27.461237303 +0000
Change: 2017-06-02 20:53:27.461237303 +0000
 Birth: -

Comment: stat OLD
  File: 'OLD'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd05h/64773d    Inode: 3227452336  Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (48935/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: (48935/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2017-06-02 20:29:05.607617334 +0000
Modify: 2017-05-12 20:20:00.000000000 +0000
Change: 2017-06-02 20:23:42.872363548 +0000
 Birth: -

Comment: cat sample.sh
#!/bin/bash
if "/home/cg/root/1/NEW" -ot "/home/cg/root/1/OLD"
then echo "file is OLD"
else echo "file is NEW"
fi

Comment: @that other guy - done

Comment: @Mikel & Charles - done

Comment: @faceless When I follow your instructions, I get the output "file is new". Can you please create a new directory and follow the instructions in your post to verify that you still see the same issue? Make sure not to reuse any of your files or previous commands, only copy-paste from this post (this is to prevent invisible or hard-to-spot errors creeping in from different versions)

Comment: @that other guy - Hello.
following your recommendation i've created everything from scratch in different directory), and it worked. Perhaps some metadata was stuck... But this is not an issue. After i succeeded, i replaced a NEW file with another file on my system (NEW="~/somefile"), which is not an empty file created by 'touch'.

Comment: @that other guy -
stat OLD
  File: ‘OLD’
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 3014670     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/XXX)   Gid: ( 1000/XXX)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2017-05-28 09:01:00.000000000 -0400
Modify: 2017-05-28 09:01:00.000000000 -0400
Change: 2017-06-04 09:01:23.013383498 -0400
 Birth: -

Comment: stat /home/somefile.xmlx
  File: ‘/home/somefile.xmlx’
  Size: 27665908        Blocks: 54040      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 3153046     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/XXX)   Gid: ( 1000/XXX)
Context: system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0
Access: 2017-06-04 07:53:12.943634353 -0400
Modify: 2017-06-02 14:36:38.267748067 -0400
Change: 2017-06-02 14:36:38.267748067 -0400
 Birth: -

Comment: @faceless That's a separate problem. `~` doesn't expand in quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing the file named in the *variable* `$NEW` and the file named in the *variable* `$OLD`, not two files named `NEW` and `OLD`.

The following behaves as expected:

```
touch NEW
touch -t $(date -d '3 week ago' +%Y%m%d%H%M) OLD
if [[ "NEW" -ot "OLD" ]]                                                          
        then echo "file is old"                                                                                       
elif [[ "NEW" -nt "OLD" ]]                                                        
        then echo "file is new"                                                                                       
fi
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. However this is not the situation here. I have variables in real, so i will remove '$' from the question.

Comment: Please ensure that your question provides a true [mcve] -- code that someone can copy-and-paste *exactly* as given to see the same problem.